# Accessing method from another class in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to access my custom method from another class in Cocos2D. This is something I have done before out with Cocos2D but for some reason it is not working now.

**heroNode.h** (CCNode)

```
@interface heroNode()

    -(void) staminaCounter;

@end

#import "heroNode.h"

@implementation heroNode {
}
        -(void)staminaCounter {
        //My Code Here

    }
@end;
```

**MainScene.h** (CCScene)

```
#import "heroNode.h"

@implementation MainScene
{
    heroNode *HeroStuff;
}

//Using
    HeroStuff = [[heroNode alloc] init];

//Then this is where I am having the issue calling `staminaCounter`
//Do something like
//[heroStuff staminaCounter];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `-(void)staminaCounter` in "heroNode.h", because if you don't do it, the method is private, you can only use it from inside your class.

Between `@interface` and `@end`

Comment: opps sorry I have already done that. Using  `[heroStuff staminaCounter];` doesn't work

Comment: You cannot do [heroNode staminaCounter] , you have defined the HeroStuff variable, so you have to do [HeroStuff staminaCounter].

By the way... your class first letter should be capitalized (HeroNode), and not your variable (heroStuff).

Comment: I was using heroStuff and it doesn't work. I get the error `no visible @interface declares.....`

Comment: that's because you have not declared `-(void)staminaCounter` in heroNode.h, check if its declared, and edit your question so we can see if it's declared correctly.

Comment: ah im a idiot. I declared it in the m file instead of h....sorry. Thanks for the help.